# The number of games in a complete pair tournament with 10 players

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In a tennis tournament in which every pair has to play a match with every other pair, $10$ players are playing. Find the number of games played.

Attempt:  Number of ways of selecting $2$ players out of $10$ for forming a pair is same as arranging them in  a row and then dividing them into groups of two
$$=\frac{10!}{(2!)^55!}=945$$

Total number of possible pairs =$945.$

These $945$ pairs have to play a match with every other possible pair.Since a pair can't play a match against itself and any other pair which has one of its member.

A pair can play only against the pairs formed by other $8$ players i.e.

$=\frac{8!}{(2!)^44!}=105$ other pairs.

So the no of games played should be $105*5$ but the text mentions the answer as $105*6$.

Where am I going wrong? What's the other way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

There are ${{10}\choose {2}}=45$ pairs.

For each of these pairs there are ${{8}\choose {2}}=28$ pairs that they must play.

So there would be $45\cdot 28$ matches played, except this double counts each match (once for each involved pair).

So there are $\frac{45\cdot 28}{2}$ matches to play.

Comment: There are $45$ or $945$ pairs?

Comment: I interpret there as being $45$ pairs.  I'm not looking at forming $5$ pairs simultaneously, I'm just looking at how many ways I can choose $2$ people from the $10$ to form one pair.

Answer (score 3):

Each match consists of $4$ players, who can be divvied into two teams in $3$ different ways.  The total number of matches is therefore

$${10\choose4}\cdot3=210\cdot3=630$$

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you are counting the number of possible assignments of **all** players into disjoint pairs, which you compute as $945$, but the question clearly asks about just the number of ways you can have one pair play against another pair, which *paw88789* has shown.